# Can I customize look of Google News RSS feed on my website?

Tags: rss, rss-reader, google-news

I have a doubt regarding the use of Google News RSS Feed. Google News help states this:

> Why Google might block an RSS feed In some cases, Google News might
> block a feed. That could happen if you are:
>
> - Using Google News feeds for profit or to increase traffic to your site
> - Reformatting news results so they look like your own content
> - Changing, editing, or creating works based on content from Google News

I am looking to clarify these points:

Can't I customize the look of the feed? I want to have a separate page for news related to content on my website. Will then I violate the second rule if I customize the look of it? For example, I'll display a slideshow on the top along with a listing in the bottom much like FeedWind or Feedgrabber widgets.

I am surely not violating the third one. But everyone displays Google News on their website to sustain traffic right? Isn't the first rule broken by everyone who uses Google news RSS feed on their website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't I customize the look of the feed?

Create an app or script to grab the feed, parse it, decorate it the way you like. Now, you have successfully customized the look.

> I want to have a separate page for news related to content on my website. Will then I violate the 2nd rule if I customize the look of it?

A bit critical question. Let me provide you a simple answer: mention at certain corner that it was from google news feed. When google shows you ads, it puts a little *AdChoice* at a cozy corner by clicking on which you can confirm that that was an ad from google - follow their strategy, give them proper credit.

> I am surely not violating the third one. But everyone displays google news on their website to sustain traffic right? Isn't the first rule broken by everyone who uses Google news rss feed on their website?

When you are providing value to others, then people like to act blind and pretend that what they see is not a promotion. For example, free medical camps are not actually done for helping others if they cannot promote them to get prospective patients (clients/customers) or cannot get free media promotion (again free flow of lot of customers) - forget those doctors who are lonely or have no responsibility or for whatever reason serving for free.